# How to save data in multiple tables using Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

How to save mixed data in multiple tables if is checked checkbox:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "rID,AgentID,karta_br,Datum,patnikID,stanicaOD,stanicaDO,cena,povratna")] tbl_rezervacii tbl_rezervacii)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (tbl_rezervacii.povratna != true)
        {
            db.tbl_rezervacii.Add(tbl_rezervacii);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
                tbl_rezervacii rezervacii = new tbl_rezervacii()
            {
               ???????????????????????
            };

            db.tbl_rezervacii.Add(rezervacii);
            db.SaveChanges();

            tbl_povratni povratni = new tbl_povratni()
            {
                ???????????????????????

            };
            db.tbl_povratni.Add(povratni);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

This is code in the controller, and I need to mix data from two forms, and save to two tables, I need something like this, and now my problem is just in else section of implementation.

I make application for Bus Ticket system, and i need this if is checked return way checkbox to add: **rID** (related with first table tbl_rezervacii), date of returning and relation of returning, include same agent id, price, etc. data which is saved in first `tbl_rezervacii` table.

MODIFIED CONTROLLER CODE:

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "rID,AgentID,karta_br,Datum,patnikID,stanicaOD,stanicaDO,cena,povratna")] tbl_rezervacii tbl_rezervacii )
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {   
            if (tbl_rezervacii.povratna != true)
            {

                db.tbl_rezervacii.Add(tbl_rezervacii);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {

                tbl_rezervacii rezervacii = new tbl_rezervacii()
                {

                    AgentID = tbl_rezervacii.AgentID,
                    karta_br = tbl_rezervacii.karta_br,
                    Datum = tbl_rezervacii.Datum,
                    patnikID = tbl_rezervacii.patnikID,
                    stanicaOD = tbl_rezervacii.stanicaOD,
                    stanicaDO = tbl_rezervacii.stanicaDO,
                    cena = tbl_rezervacii.cena,
                    povratna = tbl_rezervacii.povratna
                   };

                db.tbl_rezervacii.Add(rezervacii);
                //db.SaveChanges();
                var rows = db.SaveChanges();

                tbl_povratni povratna = new tbl_povratni()
                {
                    rezID = rezervacii.rID,
                    AgentID = rezervacii.AgentID,
                    karta_br = rezervacii.karta_br,
                    DatumP = **tbl_povratni.DatumP**,
                    patnikID = rezervacii.patnikID,
                    stanicaPOD = **tbl_povratni.stanicaPOD**,
                    stanicaPDO = **tbl_povratni.stanicaPDO**,
                };
                db.tbl_povratni.Add(povratna);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

           ViewBag.AgentID = new SelectList(db.tbl_agenti, "aID", "agent_ime", tbl_rezervacii.AgentID);
           ViewBag.patnikID = new SelectList(db.tbl_patnici, "pID", "ime", tbl_rezervacii.patnikID);
           ViewBag.stanicaOD = new SelectList(db.tbl_stanici, "sID", "stanica", tbl_rezervacii.stanicaOD); 
           ViewBag.stanicaDO = new SelectList(db.tbl_stanici, "sID", "stanica", tbl_rezervacii.stanicaDO);
          ViewBag.stanicaPOD = new SelectList(db.tbl_stanici, "sID", "stanica", tbl_rezervacii.tbl_povratni.stanicaPOD); 
          ViewBag.stanicaPDO = new SelectList(db.tbl_stanici, "sID", "stanica", tbl_rezervacii.tbl_povratni.stanicaPDO);

            return View(tbl_rezervacii);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

How to take data from secondary form and save together in second table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if checkbox is checked, you want to save data into two tables and use primary key of first table (rID) in second table? If rID is auto increment, It will be updated by EF with the value assigned by the database.

```
        tbl_rezervacii rezervacii = new tbl_rezervacii()
        {
           AgentID = tbl_rezervacii.AgendID, 
           karta_br = tbl_rezervacii.karta_br
           // and so on...
        };

        db.tbl_rezervacii.Add(rezervacii);
        var rows = db.SaveChanges(); // optional, rows will be > 0 if saved successfully.

        tbl_povratni povratni = new tbl_povratni()
        {
            // if rID is auto increment
            rID = rezervacii.rID,
            // and so on...                
        };
        db.tbl_povratni.Add(povratni);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpuful for me, and correct answer.

Comment: Just i need to add Datum2 in second tabel tbl_povratni which is diferent then Datum on first table. like **Datum2 = tbl_povratni.Datum2**. i try with this but not going. How to do it?

Comment: what is Datum2 value?

Comment: Datum2  value is secundary datum if is ckkoiced return way, and thet date must be saved on second table, if relation is just one way Datum2 is hidden form.

Comment: I modified Question, if you caaaan to help me?